# Use AWS CLI to start instance only if it's status is stopped

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm running a Jenkins server which is the AWS CLI tools installed and working. The server is running Ubuntu 16.04.3

I can successful run a command to start and stop a particular AWS instance, which is:

```
aws ec2 start-instances --region eu-west-2 --instance-ids i-65a4sd654as
```

I can also run a command to find the status of that instance:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --region eu-west-2 --instance-ids i-65a4sd654as
```

But what I need to do is run two Jenkins jobs which check the status of a particular instance, and then only runs the `start-instances` or 'stop-instances' command if the status is `stopped` or 'running', respectively.

Presumably there is a way to run one command and take the output, then make the next command conditional on that, but I can't figure out how to do this. I need the Jenkins job to show success if any of the following situations occur:

- the start job find the status is `running` so doesn't run the `start-instances` command
- the start job finds the status is `stopped` so does run the `start-instances` command, and succeeds
- the stop job finds the status is `stopped` so doesn't run the `stop-instances` command
- the stop job finds the status is `running` so does run the `stop-instances` command, and succeeds

And in all other instances to fail.

There's a wealth of information online about using each command, but nothing I can find about how to stitch them together.

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows? Depending on that, you can use bash or PowerShell to store return values to variables, and do an if check

Comment: Edited question - it's Ubuntu 16.04.3. I'm reading up on your suggestion now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a one liner on the command line, you could do something like this

```
if [[ $(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-abcd1234defg5678 --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].State[].Name' --output text) = "running" ]] ; then \
    aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-abcd1234defg5678; \
    elif [[ $(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-abcd1234defg5678 --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].State[].Name' --output text) = "stopped" ]] ; then \
    aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-abcd1234defg5678 ; \
    fi
```

Answer (score 2):

It is often easier to do this type of thing in a programming language.

Here is an example script that I use to stop instances that do *not* have a particular tag, if they are running. It doesn't exactly match your use-case, but it shows how to retrieve instances and base logic on the status and even instance tags.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto.ec2

for region in [region for region in boto.ec2.regions() if region.name not in ['us-gov-west-1', 'cn-north-1']]:
  conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region.name)
  reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
  for r in reservations:
    for i in r.instances:
      action = 'stop'
      if 'cleanup' in i.tags.keys():
        action = i.tags['cleanup'].lower()
      #print region.name, i.id, i.tags, i.state, action

      # Ignore ones marked as "ignore", or already terminated
      if action == 'ignore' or i.state == 'terminated':
        continue

      elif action in ['t', 'terminate']:
        print "Terminating", region.name, i.tags, i.state
        conn.terminate_instances([i.id])

      elif action == 'stop' and i.state != 'stopped':
        print "Stopping", region.name, i.tags, i.state
        conn.stop_instances([i.id])
```

It basically grabs a list of all instances and chooses a default action of `stop`. It then looks to see whether there is a `cleanup` tag on the instance.

If the `cleanup` tag says `ignore`, it leaves the instance alone. If the instance is tagged 't' or 'terminate', it terminates the instance. Otherwise, is stops the instance.

Comment: I accepted the answer from tkwargs as I think it suits me best, but I think this is also very useful.